# how to get Href value path and store it in String from HTML content

Tags: java

I want get all href value \\192.168.1.102\\Data\ACT\OTHERACTS\HTMLFILES\2009\ftn2csdiv2.htm  in String

Answer (score 0):

If your path is like \\SERVER\directory\file.html you could treat it as a normal file path and not URL.

An answer that covers reading text files in Java:
[Reading a plain text file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file)